# Charging Voltage of Lead Acid Batteries

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated, batteries

I recently installed a solar ups and it has been charging the batteries all the time.
I have two 12v 230ah Batteries (lead acid tubular) in series and my solar charger software says that it is charging (c.v) at 29.2 volts.
My batteries are brand new and even after a week they are still charging all the time during day time.
Battery percentage in the software is always 95% and never reaches 100% so it never stops.

What should be correct charging voltage for a flooded lead acid battery to achive 100% charge and then stop charging?

Comment: Set CV to 28.4V Max then report I vs t. Specific gravity is best indicator of SoC in each cell

Comment: Sorry what is i vs t?

Comment: Charge current vs time

Comment: Just to confirm the 28.4V, have a read : http://www.prestolite.com/pgs_training/training_3.php